# How to Authorise circle-ci with Google Cloud SQL instance

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, google-app-engine, circleci

I have NodeJS applications which utilise the SQL instance from Google App Engine. I have created a continuous integration (CI) deployment environment with CircleCI and Google App Engine. The deployment works nice. Now, I want to execute my unit tests on CircleCi. But the problem is how do I connect Google Cloud SQL instance on CircleCI?

On the local system, I use Google Cloud SQL proxy OR SSL connection to establish a connection with MySQL. How do I connect to Google Cloud SQL instance from circle-ci using NodeJs MySQL package?

Comment: Hi @AmirSaleem could you please clarify what exactly you want to achieve? Do you want to connect your Cloud SQL to Circle-Ci? Or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to establish a connection b/w cloud SQL and circle-ci. On local machine I use cloud SQL proxy or SSL based connections. How do I connect from circle-ci?